# Qt Slot with method pointer as argument

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I have a problem with slot which pass a method pointer in argument

My code work if I don't use slot, but have error when I use slot

I get error:

> *QObject::connect: No such slot CategoriesView::func1(&CategoriesView::test)*

**CategoriesView.h**

```
    public :
    typedef void (CategoriesView::*callBackMethod)(void);
    
    public slots :
    void func1(callBackMethod method);
```

**CategoriesView.cpp**

```
    void CategoriesView::func1(CategoriesView::callBackMethod method)
    {
        (this->*method)();
    }
    
    void CategoriesView::initTest()
    {
        connect(m_Timer, SIGNAL(timeout()),this , SLOT(func1(&CategoriesView::test)));
    }
    
    void CategoriesView::test()
    {
        qDebug() << "ok !";
    }
```

What I do wrong?

Comment: You can't pass arguments to slots in connect statements

Comment: Thank you, i do : connect(m_Timer, &QTimer::timeout, this , [=](){ func1(&CategoriesView::test); }); and now it works !! Thank you

Comment: Thank you, i did : connect(m_Timer, &QTimer::timeout, this , [=](){ func1(&CategoriesView::test); }); and now it works